# Fish shell function git_commit not updating command line or producing output

Tags: fish

I have defined a `git_commit` function in my Fish shell configuration file to assist with Git commits. However, when I use the function, it does not produce any errors, but it also does not result in the expected behavior. Here's the function definition:

```bash
function git_commit
    # Extract the commit message from the git_commit command
    set -l commit_msg (string replace 'git_commit (.*)' '$1' (commandline))

    # Clear the current command line in fish shell
    commandline (commandline --cut-at-cursor)

    # Set the new command line with the fixed part and the commit message
    echo -n "git commit -m $commit_msg" | commandline -r

    # Bind the Enter key to move the cursor to the desired position
    bind \r "commandline -C (math (string length 'git commit -m \"\"') - 1)"
end
```

I'm invoking the function by running `git_commit "fix typos"`. The expected behavior is that it should execute the `git commit -m` command with the provided commit message, and position the cursor at the end of the command. However, nothing happens when I run the command.

I'm using Fish shell version 3.3.1 on kubuntu.

i have created this function by read here:

- https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/function.html

### tests

#### test 1

i have added `echo "commit_msg= $commit_msg"`
inside the function and test this with no result as you could see here:

```bash
git_commit 'test'
commit_msg=
```

#### test 2

i have added `echo "commit_msg= $commit_msg"`

```bash
git_commit "test"
```

now the cursor | has moves a bit back. cursor | move to: `git_commit "tes|t"`
and `commit_msg=`  is now not visible anymore.

---

I would appreciate any help or suggestions to fix this problem. Thank you!

Comment: I don't have an answer for your specific question. Have you thought about making `git_commit` an abbreviation for `git commit -m`? If you're wanting a 2nd chance to edit the commit message, how about `function git_commit -a msg; git commit --edit -m $msg; end`

Comment: yes the idea is to not to need write "... to -m". Means fast jump to write the commit message. Maybe you put you idea as answer? i was not able to reconstruct correct what your suggested function .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems you want a second chance to rewrite the commit message, a function:

```
function gitcommit
  command git commit --edit -m (string join " " $argv)
end
```

Using `string join` means you don't even need to quote the initial message:

```
gitcommit this is my commit message
```

It's recently been suggested to me that adding the `-v` option is helpful: it includes the git diff so you can be reminded about exactly what you're committing.

---

another possibility is to use an abbreviation

```
abbr --set-cursor --add -- gitcommit 'git commit -m "%'
```

With that, you type `gitcommit` and when you hit space the abbreviation is replaced and you're now typing the commit message.

- the `set-cursor` and `%` are intended to backspace the trailing space after the opening double quote.

Comment: BTW in the question `--edit` was not used. i did this little change in my ~/.config/fish/config.fish `command git commit -m (string join " " $argv)`

Comment: but your `abbr --set-cursor --add -- gitcommit 'git commit -m "%'` seems not working for me.  `abbr: Unknown option “--set-cursor”`

Comment: I'm on a newer fish version. Try `abbr --help` to see what options are available for you

Comment: Yeah those abbr features are available since fish 3.6. You have 3.3.1, which is 2 years out of date and 15% of all commits ever made to fish behind. Fish offers official PPAs, see https://fishshell.com/, which will point you to https://launchpad.net/~fish-shell/+archive/ubuntu/release-3.